# Need to keep same # of digits in timer (Swift)

Tags: xcode, swift, function, timer, double

I have a timer that goes 1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 etc but then it goes 1.499999999 1.59999999 1.69999999 1.79999999 and on. I need it to stay with the original 2 digits. How do I do this? Here's the update function for my timer:

```
 func update() {
    // Something Swag
    if timerRunning == true{


        timerCountM += 0.1

        duringPlayTimerLbl.text = "\(timerCountM)"
    }else{

    }

}
```

Comment: why does it need to be a `Double`? Maybe add the code where you use it as a `Double`

Comment: `duringPlayTimerLbl.text = String(format: "%.1f", timerCountM)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let fmt = NSNumberFormatter()
fmt.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
fmt.maximumFractionDigits = 2 // Change this to the maximum decimals places
fmt.minimumFractionDigits = 0 // Minimum decimals. Make same as maximum to always have that amount

 func update() {
    // Something Swag
    if timerRunning {

        timerCountM += 0.1

        let formattedTimer = fmt.stringFromNumber(timerCountM)!

        duringPlayTimerLbl.text = "\(formattedTimer)"

    }else{

    }

}
```

Comment: Terrible solution.you are creating a new formatter over and over again

Comment: Btw to compare a bool == true is redundant. Only needed when used with optionals

Comment: @LeoDabus You're right, I moved it outside of the function. Make formatter global

Comment: how do i make it global and whats the difference? @Shades

Comment: When it's inside the update() function, it's being created each time update() gets called, which is a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can make `timerCountM` to be `Int` and do:

```
timerCountM += 1
text = "\(Double(timerCountM)/10)"
```